# Stop thread from re-acquiring mutex after releasing it

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, winapi, mutex

I am making my own mutex to synchronize my threads and I am having the following issue:

- The same thread seems to re-acquire the mutex right after it releases it

What I have tried:

- Telling it to yield execution to another thread (SwitchToThread, Sleep, YieldProcessor)
- Increasing delay between loops (Up to 1 second)

Here is how it works:

I have a structure with a state value:

```
volatile unsigned int state;
```

When I want to acquire the mutex, I check the state until it has been released (open), then acquire (close) it and break out of the infinite loop and do whatever needs to be done:

```
    unsigned int previous = 0;

    for (;;)
    {
        previous = InterlockedExchangeAdd(&mtx->state,
                                          0);
        if (STATE_OPEN == previous)
        {
            InterlockedExchange(&mtx->state,
                                STATE_CLOSED);

            break;
        }

        Sleep(delay);
    }
```

Then I simply release it for the next thread to acquire it:

```
InterlockedExchange(&mtx->state,
                    STATE_OPEN);
```

The way I am using it is I simply have one global volatile integer that I add 1 to in one thread and subtract 1 to in another one. Increasing the delay has helped with making it so that the number does not either go very low or very high and get stuck in a loop being executed in just a single thread, but a 1+ second delay is not going to work for my other purposes.

How could I go about making sure that all of the threads get a chance to acquire the mutex and not have it get stuck in a single thread?

Comment: _"...This makes __volatile__ objects suitable for communication with a signal handler, but not with another thread of execution..."_   https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv

Comment: But man, the Interlocked functions from the WINAPI (Meant for thread synchronization) specify volatile in the prototype. Its own purpose from what I know is to tell the compiler not to remove it or mess with it in any other way when attempting to optimize code.

Comment: @RichardCritten: That's for ISO C++. However, the code above uses the non-standard `InterlockedExchangeAdd`, which requires `volatile`. The thread safety does not come from `volatile` but from the documented behavior: "This function is atomic with respect to calls to other _interlocked_ functions.". That's rather restricted, but the code above consistently uses interlocked functions.

Comment: Are you using c or c++? Please don't tag both

Comment: I am using C but why would that matter in my case where I'm just calling the same WINAPI functions?

Answer (score 2):

The mutex does exactly what it is supposed to do: it prevents multiple threads from running at the same time.

To stop a thread from re-acquiring the mutex, the basic solution is to not access the shared resource which is protected by the mutex. The thread probably should be doing something else.

You may also have a design problem. If you have multiple resources protected by a single mutex, you may have false contention between threads. if each resource had its own mutex, multiple threads could each work on their own resource.